# Actionscript 3 Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3

I have an array that has been built and passed into actionscript from javascript. Whilst debugging I can see the object fine but when actually using the array I'm not able to access the values. Additionally when hovering over 'keywords[i]' the tooltip pops up the correct value.

The following snippet of code:

```
//build where clause
var whereClause:String = "Keyword IN (";
for(var i:int=0;i<keywords.length;i++) {
    whereClause += "'" + keywords[i] + "', ";
}

whereClause = whereClause.substr(0, whereClause.length-2);
whereClause +=") ";
```

results in the whereClause var being "Keyword IN ('undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined') "

I can see the array isn't a 'normal' actionscript array, in the watch window it gives it a type '__HTMLScriptArray' so this is obviously where the problem is coming from. Any idea how to get at the data inside the __HTMLScriptArray object?

Comment: How are you passing the data from JS to Flash?

Comment: Yes, please answer where the data comes from exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using a for-in loop instead. Something like:

```
for (var key:String in keywords) 
{
    trace(key, ':', keywords[key]); // trace for debugging, to see key and value
    whereClause += "'" + keywords[key] + "', ";
}
```

See if that works.

Comment: The difference is probably that your __HTMLScriptArray is not a flash Array type, but an object using strings as keys rather than integers. The for-in loop gives you the keys you need to access the values.

Comment: That's what I guessed at but why does hovering over keywords[i] (whilst debuging) give you the correct value in the tooltip?

Answer (score 3):

If your keywords array is valid, then you should build your where condition using a join:

```
var whereClause : String = "Keyword IN ('";
whereClause += keywords.join("', '");
whereClause += "')";
```

I that case you can skip your `whereClause = whereClause.substr(0, whereClause.length-2);`

Comment: Thats neater code (and it worked). Thanks :)

Though I should try to use a parameter and not build the where clause like this as it's used in a SQLStatement object which are pre complied. However if you change the .text property it will (understandably) have to be complied again.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this problem, is this plain Flash or Flex? (although haven't suffered from this in either), I guess you are using ExternalInterface as well. Anyway, instead of doing a normal for loop, use a for each.

Comment: I'm using Flex. I'm not using ExternalInterface. I have an initialization method that registers (or attaches) a series of methods for a 'mx:HTML' object.

I can use a work around where I pass in a pipe delimited string and turn that into an array. But I thought the original problem was interesting.

Comment: I guess the problem comes from not directly using ExternalInterface then. I've never used your method for something like this.